# Applying awk pattern to all files with same name, outputting each to a new file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to recursively find all files with the same name in a directory, apply an awk pattern to them, and then output to the directory where each of those files lives a new updated version of the file.

I thought it was better to use a for loop than xargs, but I don't exactly how to make this work...

for f in $(find . -name FILENAME.txt ); 
do awk -F"\(corr\)" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' ./FILENAME.txt > ./newFILENAME.txt $f; 
done

Ultimately I would like to be able to remove multiple strings from the file at once using -F, but also not sure how to do that using awk.

Also is there a way to remove "(cor*)" where the * represents a wildcard? Not sure how to do while keeping with the escape sequence for the parentheses

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use `(corr*)` as a field separator where `*` is a glob-style wildcard, try:

```
awk -F'[(]corr[^)]*[)]' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

For example:

```
$ echo '1(corr)2(corrTwo)3(corrThree)4' | awk -F'[(]corr[^)]*[)]' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
1 2 3 4
```

To apply this command to every file under the current directory named `FILENAME.txt`, use:

```
find . -name FILENAME.txt -execdir sh -c 'awk -F'\''[(]corr[^)]*[)]'\'' '\''{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'\'' "$1" > ./newFILENAME.txt' Awk {} \;
```

#### Notes

Don't use:

```
for f in $(find . -name FILENAME.txt ); do
```

If any file or directory has whitespace or other shell-active characters in it, the results will be an unpleasant surprise.

#### Handling both parens and square brackets as field separators

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.txt
1(corr)2(corrTwo)3[some]4
```

To eliminate both types of separators and print the first four columns:

```
$ awk -F'[(]corr[^)]*[)]|[[][^]]*[]]' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file.txt
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: If I wanted to remove multiple strings using awk, would I use && ?

Comment: You're welcome,  _"If I wanted to remove multiple strings..."_  What does that mean?  Show me sample sample input and corresponding output with these "multiple strings".

Comment: Just like I removed everything in the form (corr*), I would like to remove everything in the form [*] as well from the input.    so input is 0.001998002 (corrected)    0.8450    0.0870    0.1550         0.000999001 (corrected) [PM SEM last > EM SEM] and output is just the numbers

Comment: @Ducki See updated answer for a method to handle both types of separators.